# How to inject IDistributedCache in a business class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, redis

I have an asp.net core project and I'm trying to use `IDistributedCache` (Redis).

I want to access `IDistributedCache` in a custom class, not only in a controller.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. register it with container and have it as an injectable argument on custom class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to access IDistributedCache in a custom class, not only in a controller. Is that possible?

**Yes.**

Register with service collection

```
var redisconnection = "...";
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(o => { o.Configuration = redisconnection; });
services.AddScoped<MyCustomClass>();

//...
```

and have it as an injectable argument on custom class

```
public MyCustomClass(IDistributedCache cache) {
    //...
}
```